# Cant preserve folder contents that are automatically created by another script

Tags: 20.04, permissions

I am struggling to preserve the directory contents as they are automatically created by a script and are disappearing, hence next script fails as it cannot find the required path.

**ERROR**
no such file or directory, open '/etc/octopus/Cypress-worker/Work/20221221121635-45089-396/P360SmokeTest/mochawesome.html'

I have the directory created(/etc/octopus/Cypress-worker/Work/20221221121635-45089-396) but with no contents in it. I have tried chattr -R -i Cypress-worker/ and chattr -a Work/ but of no use.

I am new to Linux(Ubuntu) world, any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Pari

Comment: Something else is happening there, because files created through a script are not automatically deleted unless another dedicated script would do so. It is impossible for us to know what you did on the system that would cause such a behavior. As a new Ubuntu user, you probably should be working under your home directory, and leave changing system files to the time where you are more knowledge and experienced.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advise!